# What are the initial conditions associated with solving the geodesic equation in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics

Can we say that initial conditions for solving the geodesic equation in general relativity be intial velocity of a particle?

Answer (score 5):

The most practical way to solve the geodesic equations is using a dynamical systems approach, where one re-writes the 2nd-order ODEs as a coupled system of first-order ODEs. Let the geodesic equation be given as:

$\ddot{x}^a + \Gamma^{a}_{bc} \dot{x}^{b} \dot{x}^{c} = 0$.

Then, this can be written as a system of first-order equations as follows:

$\dot{x}^{a} = y^{a}$,

$\dot{y}^{a} = -\Gamma^{a}_{bc} y^{b} y^{c}$

Now, this is a dynamical system, and while explicit solutions may not be possible, one can use all the beautiful tools of dynamical systems theory to get a very detailed description of information about the system. (It's also much easier to solve numerically when cast in this form!) The initial conditions are $(x^a_i, y^a_i)$.

Comment: If we do not make this split and just try to find the geodesic between two events, is the knowledge of the two points enough? Well it seems so, but I have a question. Imagine being on the surface of a sphere and the two points in the problem are the north and south pole. Then, we know there is a family of geodesics possible for the particle to move between the points. We have two initial conditions but still the solution is not unique, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The geodesic equation

$$\frac{d^2 x^{\mu}}{ds^2} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\rho\sigma} \frac{dx^{\rho}}{ds}\frac{dx^{\sigma}}{ds}=0$$

is nothing more than a set of (coupled) second-order differential equations for the particle's coordinates as a function of some parameter $s$. The explicit solution

$$x^{\mu}(s)$$
 requires an initial coordinate position $x^{\mu}(s_0)$ and an initial coordinate velocity $\frac{dx^{\mu}(s_0)}{ds}$. Note it is often not practical to find an explicit solution, and it is more useful to study various aspects of the equations.